# Which font you use to program?

Tags: fonts

For my curiosity and also a bit of necessity, I wanted to ask you this very border-line question with stackOverflow.
I would like to ask this question here to hear the idea of ​​some real programmers, not to hear some useless ads and absurd ideas that come up googling this question.

So,
**What kind of fonts do you use in programming?**
There are several font types but I like them clear and legible like [Fira code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode)

But since I would like to broaden my mind and change the type of font, I wanted to know **your gently opinions** about the font to use during a favolous programming session✨

Thanks for help

Comment: Opinions are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: yes but an answer is equivalent to an opinion seeing it philosophically .. and really I want to know some ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm using Visual Studio Code And to choose my favourite programming font i used this [website](https://www.slant.co/topics/67/%7Ebest-programming-fonts)
I 'be used Fira code too but now that I've tried [Source code pro](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Code+Pro) i can't switch it anymore!!

Take a look, it's a monospaced sans serif typeface very useful and gracious.

Another one is [Hack](https://sourcefoundry.org/hack/)
It's really attractive for Letters, punctuation, and symbols because are well-balanced and easily distinguished.

So good luck in your research.

Comment: thanks Hack inspires me, and I'm gonna try also dejaVu sans mono